# What does "new ()" do inside "static" and how does "static" alone not throw a compile/run error?

Tags: java, scala, decompiling

I have made a very simple Scala program which just prints `Hello World`:

```
object HelloWorldActivity {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("Hello, world")
    }
}
```

To understand how Scala converts to Java bytecode I decompiled the resulting *jar* file where there are two files: `HelloWorldActivity.class` and `HelloWorldActivity$.class`.

The first one contains this code:

```
import scala.reflect.ScalaSignature;

@ScalaSignature(bytes="****************")
public final class HelloWorldActivity
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    HelloWorldActivity..MODULE$.main(paramArrayOfString);
  }
}
```

while the second one contains:

```
import scala.Predef.;

public final class HelloWorldActivity$
{
  public static final  MODULE$;

  static
  {
    new ();
  }

  public void main(String[] args)
  {
    Predef..MODULE$.println("Hello, world");
  }

  private HelloWorldActivity$()
  {
    MODULE$ = this;
  }
}
```

what I can't understand is what the following does:

```
  static
  {
    new ();
  }
```

What's the reason to put an empty `new ()` inside `static`, and how does `static` alone not throw a compile/run error?

If it helps I'm using http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html

and having this in `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies{
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.1"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The decompiler isn't producing valid Java code there.

Here's what `javap -p -v 'HelloWorldActivity$'` shows:

```
public static {};
  descriptor: ()V
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
  Code:
  stack=1, locals=0, args_size=0
     0: new           #2                  // class HelloWorldActivity$
     3: invokespecial #12                 // Method "<init>":()V
     6: return
```

That's just creating a new instance of the class. So, the decompiler should have showed this code for the static initialiser:

```
static {
   new HelloWorldActivity$();
}
```

The static initialiser is executed once when the class is first loaded. This would typically occur when the main method in `HelloWorldActivity` is first executed, because that's where the code that uses `HelloWorldActivity$` is.

Note that the static initialiser isn't storing the reference to the newly created instance. Instead, the constructor stores the reference to `this` (i.e. the reference to the singleton instance) into the `MODULE$` field.

```
private HelloWorldActivity$();
  descriptor: ()V
  flags: ACC_PRIVATE
  Code:
  stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: aload_0
     1: invokespecial #29                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4: aload_0
     5: putstatic     #31                 // Field MODULE$:LHelloWorldActivity$;
     8: return
```

Or, as your decompiler correctly shows:

```
private HelloWorldActivity$() {
    MODULE$ = this;
}
```

**Edit:** Regarding the `static {…}` syntax for defining a static initialiser, see the *Java Language Specification [§8.7 Static Initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)* for a reference.
 It's also possible to write an instance initialiser, by writing a `{…}` block in your class. Instance initialisers are executed when creating each instance of the class, in much the same way as field initialisation is performed.

Comment: More germanely, why expect a java decompiler to produce sane results? The `Predef..Module$` syntax is also borked. Since dollar-mangled Scala naming wreaks havoc with `getClass.getSimpleName`, it's a stretch to decompile to java.

Comment: That's weird. I've been using `jd-gui` to decompile the classes. @som-snytt If you don't mind, are you aware of any decompiler which produces sane results?

Comment: To witness desugaring and implicit application, use `scalac -Xprint:typer`; to see what you wind up with, use the REPL's `:javap` to run `javap`. But the REPL ought to have its own byte code printer with an option to attempt decompile or at least correlate byte code artifacts with source.

Comment: I've seen jd-gui produce invalid Java when decompiling bytecode compiled from Java, so no wonder it's struggling with Scala. The only reason I've ever persevered with it is that I like the UI.

Answer (score 0):

in java class load proses is being like this:

> 1.load static variables and methods
>
> 2.load instance variables and methods.

and static block
`static {//some code}`
is for loading or doing something when compiler load static variables and methods.
look at this:

public class Test {

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Test();
   }

   public Test() {
      System.out.println("i am here");
   }

   static int f = 10;

   static{
      System.out.println(f);
   }
 }
```

first we should think that result is :
i am here
10

but result is
10
i am here

because of static variables,methods,blocks are loading first.also there is instance blocks.like this:

```
{
    System.out.println("i am in instance block");
}
```

this will load when instance variables,methods and blocks loading step

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, Java compiler does not generate `.class` files of classes which are not instantiated anywhere in the code. Since there is no static `main` method and no creation of instance, I'd say it's wise.

I have no idea how it's valid, maybe it's specific to `.class` files.